# Configure Python logger by looking at well-known paths

Tags: python, logging

I'm used to Java logging libraries (eg. log4j), which don't require any programmatic setup, one places a well-known file name (eg, log4j.xml) in one expected path (eg, program's initial directory) and that is picked automatically and used to setup things like logging file and format.

I know it wouldn't be difficult to implement the same in Python, but I don't like to reinvent wheels, is such a feature already available in the standard logging module or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

There are no such well-known log configuration file names for the `logging` module in Python.

However you can still use `logging.config.fileConfig` to configure your logger based on a configuration file which is in a [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#module-configparser) compatible format.
Or if you need more granular control you can use the `logging.config.dictConfig` method, it's the best if you want to store your configuration in a different format, like `json`, `yaml`, etc.

You can check out the documentation for further reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#configuration-functions

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look on Python [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) and [Logging HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html).

Following code sample is from the section [Logging to a file](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file) in HOWTO page and may be used as a start point.

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
logging.error('And non-ASCII stuff, too, like Øresund and Malmö')
```

For more detailed control over formatting, take a look at [Formatters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#formatter-objects) from 'logging' module. And finally, if you are interested in having as similar logs as possible to log4j, [this module](https://pypi.org/project/XMLLayout/) may be interesting for you.

Comment: This is what I'm already doing, I'd like to be able to avoid any config step.